# Excel macro leaves formulas in fields as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lengthy VBA macro that places contents into an Excel sheet. Some of the contents are simple formulas, like `=Q7*.3`. When the macro completes, these appear as text in the cells, instead of the values. F9 does not fix it.

Now if I simply click on one of these cells, then in the edit bar and hit return, the formula instantly calculates properly. From then on,everything works for that cell.

I recall seeing this before, but I cannot recall the solution

- yes, the format is set to a numeric format
- yes, I tried changing the format manually with no effect
- yes, I send a .Calculate to the sheet, as well as doing so manually
- no, there is no leading quote or anything like that
- no, I don't change anything to get it to calculate properly, simply hit return in the edit bar

It *appears* to be some sort of status flag not getting set on the cell so Excel doesn't think it ever has to calc it? Example:

```
TempD = GetFXRate("HUF")
WS.Cells(R, 20).Formula = "=Q" & R & IIf(Round(TempD, 4) = 1, "", "*" & TempD)
```

All values and constants are valid. TempD is ~0.3. All of the referenced cells exist. R=7 for the first iteration.

Comment: Are you using `<range>.Formula` or `<range>.Value` to place contents through VBA?

Comment: WS.Cells(R, 19).Formula = "=Q7*" & FXRate

Comment: always best to post the piece of code that is producing this issue otherwise we are just guessing at what is wrong.

Comment: What is tempD? I mean what type.

Comment: the only way I can reproduce that is by setting the numberformat of the cell to  text before setting the formula.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I'm with Nick on this.

Comment: What is the numberformat of the cell **before** you update the value with `.formula=`? If you are changing to general numberformat **after** the value is set you will see the behaviour you have described here.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be in the piece of code you posted. Check if something else in the code is working on the range.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your 'answer' based on my final comment, the only possible solution can be that your `normal` cell style is set to `text`, this way your new sheets are being added with a `normal` style of `text` instead of `general`.

You can change this by right clicking on the `normal` style on the `cell styles` section of the `home` tab and clicking `modify`.

[image: Modify Cell Style]

Click the `format` button, select `general` and click `ok` and then `ok` again.

[image]

Run your script again, and you should find that your new sheets are created with a general numberformat for all cells.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs depending on the way the sheet is initially made. If you create the sheet manually it gets the correct format an everything works. If you create the sheet in VBA code, it apparently sets the default format to something different - **not** text, some sort of indeterminate format. So even if you don't apply a single .NumberFormat anywhere in your code, or odder still go ahead and set the format properly at some point later, it still ends up in this weird state. I consider this to be a bug.

In any event the solution is to set the format of all cells once immediately after creation:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = WB.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
WS.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
```

Inserting from that point works fine, as does setting the format.

Comment: Again, I cannot reproduce this. Without you posting more complete code (including the bit where you create the sheet) so we can analyse what is happening this is **not** the correct answer. Besides, it does just kind of draw on my last comment for the solution which is a bit rude!